# Google Script Triggers no longer working due to authorization issue with Twitter API v1.1

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth

I am using a Google Script to feed information from an API to a Twitter feed. I have to date managed this by using minute-by-minute triggers to check the API, see if there have been changes, and if so authorise with Twitter and tweet.

Since the change to Twitter API v1.1, the script works ok if I press run and Authorize when the prompt appears, but not when it's triggered.

My authorization function is as follows:

```
function authorize() {

  var oauthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("twitter");

  oauthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl(
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token");
  oauthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl(
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token");
  oauthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl(
    "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
  oauthConfig.setConsumerKey('[key]');
  oauthConfig.setConsumerSecret('[key]');
};
```

Can anyone advise:

1. How I can fix this problem
2. An alternative solution. I am relatively new to programming - I only have experience with JavaScript (primarily through Google Script) and Python so any solutions using these would be preferred.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If it is the same twitter user each time, is there a need to re-authorize each time?

Comment: Yes. If I comment out the authorize() step the "twitter" oAuthServiceName doesn't exist for requestData: . Has the protocol for authorization retention changed in v1.1? Thanks for your input

Comment: var requestData = {
  
    "method": "GET",
    "oAuthServiceName": "twitter",
    "oAuthUseToken": "always"
  };`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Twitter recently updated the accepted characters contained in tweets. For instance if you try to post a single quote (`'`), your tweet will be rejected by the API and your access token revoked. You will therefore have to re-identify yourself each time.

So look at the symbols contained in your tweets and try to remove `(`, `)` and `'` to debug and see if the problem comes from that.

More info about that [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2936#c12).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that may have been it. In the end I just rewrote the script in Python and am running it on an AWS instance.